# Django Rest Framework 3.0: Saving Nested, Many-To-One Relationship

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to build a nested relationship using Django Rest Framework 3.0. I've created my serializers and have attempted to override the `create()` function. My models are defined as follows:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='prices')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost = models.FloatField()
```

As you'll note, I can have multiple prices for my items. My serializers are defined as follows:

```
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
        exclude = ('user',)

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prices = PriceSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'prices', 'categories')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.get('user')

        # Get our categories
        category_data = validated_data.pop('categories')

        # Create our item
        item = Item.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # Process the categories. We create any new categories, or return the ID of existing
        # categories.
        for category in category_data:
            category['name'] = category['name'].title()
            category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(user=user, **category)
            item.categories.add(category.id)

        item.save()

        return item
```

When I try and POST a new item:

```
{
    "name": "Testing",
    "description": "This is a test",
    "categories": [
        {
            "name": "foo"
        },
        {
            "name": "bar"
        }
    ],
    "prices": [
        {
            "name": "Red",
            "cost": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "prices": [
        {
            "item": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Presumably because the Price serializer has no idea what the ID of the new item is. I've tried overriding this functionality in the `create()` function of my serializer, but it appears as though the serializer's validation is being hit before I have the opportunity to create the item and associate it with the price.

So - How do I create a new item, get the item ID, and then create each of the new prices?

Comment: Do you even reach the `create` method when posting your data?

Comment: @SimonCharette With the code posted above, no, it doesn't appear that I ever hit the `create` function. However, if I mark the price as not required and don't POST it in the JSON, the create function is executed just fine. This leads me to believe that the validation is being called on the data before I have the opportunity to handle it. I tried overwriting the validation function to no avail...

Comment: Can you paste the code for `CategorySerializer`.

Comment: Just a heads up, you should avoid using `exclude` for fields and instead just specify `fields` with the ones you are planning on using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `PriceSerializer` is looking for the `item` key because it is specified on the `Price` model. This isn't immediately obvious because you are using `Meta.exclude` instead of `Meta.fields`.

```
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Is the same as writing

```
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ('id', 'item', 'name', 'cost', )
```

Which makes it very clear what your issue is. Because your `item` field on the model does not have `empty=True` (or `null=True`) set, Django REST Framework automatically [generates it as a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) with `required=True`. This is why you are getting the `This field is required` is required error, because Django REST Framework cannot automatically detect that it is coming from a parent serializer which already has that field.

You can get around this by removing the field from the serializer, as it doesn't appear to ever be needed.

```
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'cost', )
```

This will no longer display the `item` field though, but I suspect this isn't actually an issue for you.

Comment: Yup, this works! A misunderstanding on my part about how the nested serialization would work.